# Getting value of a tensor variable in Theano

Tags: theano

I am a noob at Theano - so please be patient.

I'm trying to implement gradient clipping for a project. A code snippet is as below :

```
grads = tensor.grad(cost, wrt=itemlist(tparams))

grad_norm = tensor.sqrt(sum(map(lambda x: tensor.sqr(x).sum(), grads)))
grad_norm = tensor.sqrt(grad_norm)
print grad_norm.eval()
```

The error I receive is as follows :

`theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to    compute Shape(x), was not provided and not given a value.Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high',for more information on this error.", x)`

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `eval` without providing the input values.

Your code is incomplete so I'm guessing a bit but `cost` is probably a function of at least one input tensor (e.g. something like `x = T.matrix()`). That being the case, a value needs to be provided for `x` when the computation is executed. You execute the computation by calling `eval` and can provide a value for `x` like this:

```
print grad_norm.eval({x: numpy.random.randn(10, 20).astype(theano.config.floatX})
```

You need to make sure you provide a value for every symbolic input that, in this case, `grad_norm` is a function of (just add additional entries to the dictionary passed to `eval`). You also need to make sure the shapes of the values passed in the dictionary are appropriate for the computation (e.g. if there's a dot product with a shared variable, the multiplied axes must be of the same size).

Also, be aware, the `eval` method is intended primarily for debug purposes. You shouldn't use this feature in 'real' code. Instead, you should compile the computation using `theano.function`.